# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: null during camel route shutdown

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

I have a camel route which I am trying to shutdown in case I encounter a java.net.ConnectException. 
In my shutdown strategy, I am removing the keys that I had added in the context properties during the route execution and then shutting down the route as follows:

```
exchange.getContext().stopRoute(routeid,10000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

But, everytime this line is encountered, I get java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: null exception. I tried increasing the timeout interval but the problem still persists. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: i think it should be shutdownRoute(routeId, timeout, timeUnit) for shutting down a route. Refer http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html